# Unintended characters being sent to output

Tags: autohotkey

Below script :

```
:*:mw::
    Send, {Ctrl Down}{RWin Down}{x Down}{Ctrl Up}{RWin Up}{x Up}
```

sends characters "cp" to screen once it runs.

So if I am in a text editor and type "mw" then "cp" is sent to the editor.

How can amend the script so that it just fires the keys "Ctrl,WindowsKey,x" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `return`:

```
:*:mw::
    Send, {Ctrl Down}{RWin Down}{x Down}{Ctrl Up}{RWin Up}{x Up}
    return  ; Add this to return without continuing to execute statements after this line

Send, cp  ; Just a guess, I think you have this line somewhere here
```

You can omit `return` if `Send` is at the same line as the hotkey:

```
:*:mw::Send, {Ctrl Down}{RWin Down}{x Down}{Ctrl Up}{RWin Up}{x Up}
```